# Newest version of lzo.dll for use with lzo.net (in memory compression)

Tags: c#, compilation, lzo

for use with lzo-net ( http://lzo-net.sourceforge.net/ ) I am looking for a new version of the lzo.dll file. Mine is from 2004.

The newest file should be 2.0.6 ( http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/download/ )

But I only have visual studio and compiling is not working. I run

```
lzo-2.05\B\win32>vc_dll.bat
```

But I only get error messages.

Where can I download the newsest x86 version of lzo.dll?

I compared compression speed with very much other tools (SharpZipLip, DotNetZip, ManagedQLZ, QuickLZSharp, MiniLZO, Deflate, SevenZip), but lzo is the fastest for my application.

So it would be the best to use the newest version available I think. Maybe there are other improovements and bug fixes that help.

I get the followign errors:

```
D:\lzo-2.05\lzo-2.05\B\win32>vc_dll.bat
// Copyright (C) 1996-2011 Markus F.X.J. Oberhumer
//
//   Windows 32-bit
//   Microsoft Visual C/C++ (DLL)
//
The system cannot find the path specified.

D:\lzo-2.05\lzo-2.05\B\win32>set CC=cl -nologo -MD

D:\lzo-2.05\lzo-2.05\B\win32>set CF=-O2 -GF -W3

D:\lzo-2.05\lzo-2.05\B\win32>set LF=

D:\lzo-2.05\lzo-2.05\B\win32>cl -nologo -MD -O2 -GF -W3   -D__LZO_EXPO
RT1#__declspec(dllexport) -c @b\src.rsp
The command "cl" is either misspelled or could not be found
```

Comment: What makes you think there is a newer version, it looks like lzo.net hasn't been updated in a while.

Comment: @Ben Robinson, there is lzo-2.0.6.tar.gz at   http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/download/

Comment: @Chris, could you post the error messages?

Comment: @axel_c I have updated my post. I thin cl is a compiler the bat file needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the .bat file is not finding the CL (commandline VC compiler) in your PATH. Have you tried running the vc_dll.bat file from a Visual Studio command prompt? It should be somewhere in the "visual studio tools" group in your Start menu.

Additionally, the documentation says:

> To build LZO for your system type 'b\OS\COMPILER' in the base
>   directory, e.g. 'b\win32\vc.bat' will build the Win32 Visual C/C++
>   version.

So you're building from the wrong directory. You **MUST** be in the base directory  (eg. D:\lzo-2.05\lzo-2.05) and from there execute:

```
b\win32\vc_dll.bat
```

Comment: Yes, the thing with the path is the problem. But now I get hundret of other errors. Mostly the .h files it does not found. It needs the full path to everything not just b/src.rsp for example. I think I need to adjust all Pathes.

Comment: Uhm, don't think so. There's probably a single thing that is making everything else fail. Investigate that, rather than jump into changing everything. If there's a bat specifically for building with VC++ there's good reason to believe it works... examine the initial errors closely for 'command not found' or similar errors

Comment: The problem is for example with this line:
%CC% %CF% -D__LZO_EXPORT1#__declspec(dllexport) -c @b\src.rsp

It does not recognize b\src.rsp
But it is there (D:\lzo-2.05\lzo-2.05\b\src.rsp).
And I am in the folder D:\lzo-2.05\lzo-2.05\B\win32, so it should work. When I am using the full bath for src.rsp it is working. I have the same problem everywhere. Just adding these pathes to the PATH variable does not help.

Comment: See my edited answer, you're executing from the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a [CLI C++ .NET wrapper for LZO](http://lzohelper.codeplex.com/) that uses the current LZO2 DLL. In case anyone is looking for a more up to date .NET interface.